# AngularJS: Unexpected ngResource get() behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to fire a simple GET request from my angular app via $resource service (so there is no need to say that I am new to Angular). Since my server side behaves in RESTfull manner, I am trying to use the nice Angular ngResource. Before trying to generate the GET request from my Angular app, I tested the availability of the resource and it returns the expected information when requested.

My service:

```
services.factory('ScreenInitializer', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/angular/screenInitializer/:initializerParameter',
            {initializerParameter : '@sectionName'});
}]);
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('HomePageController', ['$scope', 'ScreenInitializer', function($scope, ScreenInitializer) {
    $scope.searchByOptions = ScreenInitializer.get({sectionName: "homePageSearchBy"});
    // Some irrelevant stuff here...
}
```

My expectation:
According to the book I read and some examples in the net, what I expected is the parameter `initilizeParam` in the resource URL to be replaced with the argument that I pass to the `.get()` method and as a result to have a GET request at

> localhost:8080/angular/screenInitilizer/homePageSearchBy

What actually happened:
is a GET request where the `"homePageSearchBy"` is passed as parameter -  `localhost:8080/angular/screenInitializer?sectionName=homePageSearchBy`. Due to that the server responds with 404 - Resource not found. (which is expected since its location is at .../screenInitializer/homePageSearchBy)

My question:
Is my expectation wrong, or I am using ngResource in a bad way?.

Thanks!

Comment: Why won't you simply do `return $resource('/angular/screenInitializer/:sectionName');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value of that parameter is extracted from the **data object** (useful for **non-GET** operations).

So this

```
{initializerParameter : '@sectionName'}
```

Is irrelevant for GET operations. And this

```
{sectionName: "homePageSearchBy"}
```

appends a `sectionName` parameter because the URL template does not contain `sectionName`. What you need is

```
ScreenInitializer.get({initializerParameter : "homePageSearchBy"})
```

Comment: Thanks zeroflagL it is working pretty well. It seems my way of understanding the parametrized URLs in Angular was pretty bad :).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to new it up, but if you pass an empty object to the `get` it will work.  See below.

```
$scope.screen = new ScreenInitialize({sectionName: "homePageSearchBy"});
$scope.screen.$get(function(result){ .. do something ..}, function(error){ .. do something ..})
```

---

```
$scope.searchByOptions = ScreenInitializer.get({}, {sectionName: "homePageSearchBy"});
```

Example plunkr showing the urls (you have to inspect):

http://embed.plnkr.co/kQsMujk9IgGxdxSE2g0E/

Code:

```
 var Screen = $resource(
    '/angular/screenInitializer/:initializerParameter',
     {initializerParameter : '@sectionName'});
  $scope.screen = Screen.get({}, {sectionName: "homePageSearchBy"});
```

The url this calls:

> http://run.plnkr.co/angular/screenInitializer/homePageSearchBy

Comment: Big thanks for the answer. It is working exactly as I expect it to work. The bad part is that I don't quite understand why, but this is a matter of investigation. It's a valid and good solution! However my case was very very simple and zeroflagL below gave very easy and understandable solution to my simple problem. However if anyone get link to that topic, just keep in mind that the solution above is working!